# Insert a String of numbers into a matrix

Tags: java

I'm kind of stuck in this algorithm. I have this function below that gets a String and a matrix[n][m]. 
The String has up to n*m digits, and I need to insert them by reverse from the last digit to the last cell of the matrix, respectively, until I reach the first cell;

For example: the String='3' will be like that {[0][0],[0][3]}; the String='123' will be like that {[0][1],[2][3]}; and the String='2222' will be like that {[2][2],[2][2]};

The issue is: For the String '123' I get a matrix {[1][1],[1][1]}. It seems like only the first digit insert into the matrix.

```
stringToInteger(String correctBase, int [][] board)
{
    int integerNum;

    for(int i=correctBase.length()-1; i>=0; i--)         
    {
        integerNum=correctBase.charAt(i)-'0';               
        for(int row=board.length-1; row>=0; row--)       
            for(int col=board[row].length-1; col>=0; col--)
                board[row][col]=integerNum;
    }
```

Comment: so what's the issue?

Comment: That it doesn't work well. For the String '123' I get a matrix {[1][1],[1][1]}. It seems like only the first digit insert into the matrix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
stringToInteger(String correctBase, int [][] board)
{
    int integerNum;
    int row = board.length - 1;
    int col = board[0].length - 1;

    for(int i=correctBase.length()-1; i>=0; i--)         
    {
        integerNum=correctBase.charAt(i)-'0';
        board[row][col]=integerNum;
        col--;
        if(col < 0) {
            col = board[0].length - 1;
            row--;
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: You just forgot this inside the for loop: integerNum=correctBase.charAt(i)-'0';

Answer (score 0):

Yes, or:

```
    int i = correctBase.length();
    for(int row=board.length-1; row>=0; row--)       
        for(int col=board[row].length-1; col>=0; col--)
            board[row][col] = i > 0 ? correctBase.get(--i)-'0' : 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

I would first check if the size of the string matches the size of the matrix. If it does not, then pad said string with zeroes. Then just parse the positions of the string and insert them into the matrix.

Try it like this.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    //define size of matrix
    int n = 2;
    int m = 2;

    String input = "3";

    //if size of string is less than matrix size we append 0 to it
    if (input.length() < n * m) {
        int diff = n * m - input.length();

        for (int i = 0; i < diff; i++)
            input = "0" + input; //pad zeroes to the string
    }

    int board[][] = new int[n][m]; //declare matrix

    //populate matrix
    int stringPosition = 0; //position in the string starting from the left
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < m; j++) {
                board[i][j] =
                        Character.getNumericValue(input.charAt(stringPosition)); //transfrom char to int, then assign it to matrix
            stringPosition++; //increment position
        }
    }

    //display matrix
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < m; j++) {
            System.out.println("board[" + i + "][" + j + "] = " + board[i][j]);
        }
    }
}
```

It produces the desired results

```
input="3"

board[0][0] = 0
board[0][1] = 0
board[1][0] = 0
board[1][1] = 3


input="123"

board[0][0] = 0
board[0][1] = 1
board[1][0] = 2
board[1][1] = 3


input="2222"

board[0][0] = 2
board[0][1] = 2
board[1][0] = 2
board[1][1] = 2
```